# Mysql multiple select multiple where quick and efficient?

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I have the following mysql query which is working properly, only problem being : it is really slow. Could anybody suggest me if there is a better quicker way to execute such query??

```
SELECT 
(select sum(tot) FROM NOI_per_order_perf_global WHERE DATE(datte) = DATE(NOW()) AND origin_country = 'fr') as yoofr,
(select sum(tot) FROM table1 WHERE DATE(datte) = DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND  contry = 'fr') as yooyestfr, 
(select sum(tot) FROM table1 WHERE yearweek(`datte`, 1) = yearweek(curdate(), 1) AND YEAR(datte)=2014 AND contry = 'fr') as yooyesttfr,
(select sum(tot) FROM table1 WHERE MONTH(datte) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(datte)=2014 AND contry = 'fr') as yooyestttfr,
(select MAX(datte) FROM table1 WHERE contry = 'fr') as timingfr,

(select sum(tot) FROM table1 WHERE DATE(datte) = DATE(NOW()) AND contry = 'de') as yoode,
(select sum(tot) FROM table1 WHERE DATE(datte) = DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND  contry = 'de') as yooyestde, 
(select sum(tot) FROM table1 WHERE yearweek(`datte`, 1) = yearweek(curdate(), 1) AND YEAR(datte)=2014 AND contry = 'de') as yooyesttde,
(select sum(tot) FROM table1 WHERE MONTH(datte) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(datte)=2014 AND contry = 'de') as yooyestttde,
(select MAX(datte) FROM table1 WHERE contry = 'de') as timingde,

(select sum(tot) FROM table1 WHERE DATE(datte) = DATE(NOW()) AND contry = 'it') as yooit,
(select sum(tot) FROM table1 WHERE DATE(datte) = DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND  contry = 'it') as yooyestit, 
(select sum(tot) FROM table1 WHERE yearweek(`datte`, 1) = yearweek(curdate(), 1) AND YEAR(datte)=2014 AND contry = 'it') as yooyesttit,
(select sum(tot) FROM table1 WHERE MONTH(datte) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(datte)=2014 AND contry = 'it') as yooyestttit,
(select MAX(datte) FROM table1 WHERE contry = 'it') as timingit,

(select sum(tot) FROM table1 WHERE DATE(datte) = DATE(NOW()) AND contry = 'es') as yooes,
(select sum(tot) FROM table1 WHERE DATE(datte) = DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND  contry = 'es') as yooyestes, 
(select sum(tot) FROM table1 WHERE yearweek(`datte`, 1) = yearweek(curdate(), 1) AND YEAR(datte)=2014 AND contry = 'es') as yooyesttes,
(select sum(tot) FROM table1 WHERE MONTH(datte) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(datte)=2014 AND contry = 'es') as yooyestttes,
(select MAX(datte) FROM table1 WHERE contry = 'es') as timinges,
```

thanks, marko.

Comment: It would be helpful to include an explanation of what exactly you are trying to do in the code.

Comment: You might want to check `UNION` but honestly, if you need this for real world code, you seriously might want to rethink your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bringing back one row per county might be a bit more efficient:-

```
SELECT origin_country, 
        SUM(IF(DATE(datte) = DATE(NOW()), tot, 0)) AS yoofr,
        SUM(IF(DATE(datte) = DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY, tot, 0)) AS yooyestfr, 
        SUM(IF(yearweek(`datte`, 1) = yearweek(curdate(), 1) AND YEAR(datte)=2014, 0)) AS yooyesttfr,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(datte) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(datte)=2014, 0)) AS yooyestttfr,
        MAX(datte) AS timingfr
FROM table1
WHERE origin_country IN ('fr', 'de', 'it', 'es')
GROUP BY origin_country
```

But this is still not going to be great (indexes are not going to be that much use in the sum fields)

Possibly this, which will allow indexes to be used (if there are useful ones):-

```
SELECT sub1.origin_country, yoofr, yooyestfr, yooyesttfr, yooyestttfr, timingfr
FROM
(
    SELECT origin_country, sum(tot) as yoofr,
    FROM table1
    WHERE origin_country IN ('fr', 'de', 'it', 'es')
    AND DATE(datte) = DATE(NOW())
    GROUP BY origin_country
) sub1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT origin_country, sum(tot) as yooyestfr 
    FROM table1
    WHERE origin_country IN ('fr', 'de', 'it', 'es')
    AND DATE(datte) = DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    GROUP BY origin_country
) sub2 ON sub1.origin_country = sub2.origin_country
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT origin_country, sum(tot) as yooyesttfr 
    FROM table1
    WHERE origin_country IN ('fr', 'de', 'it', 'es')
    AND yearweek(`datte`, 1) = yearweek(curdate(), 1) AND YEAR(datte)=2014
    GROUP BY origin_country
) sub3 ON sub1.origin_country = sub3.origin_country
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT origin_country, sum(tot) as yooyestttfr 
    FROM table1
    WHERE origin_country IN ('fr', 'de', 'it', 'es')
    AND MONTH(datte) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(datte)=2014
    GROUP BY origin_country
) sub4 ON sub1.origin_country = sub4.origin_country
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT origin_country, MAX(datte) as timingfr 
    FROM table1
    WHERE origin_country IN ('fr', 'de', 'it', 'es')
    GROUP BY origin_country
) sub5 ON sub1.origin_country = sub5.origin_country
```

However a lot of this will depend on the indexes on your actual tables

Comment: cool, I actually have no indexes in my table. I guess that I could build one using the fields present in my group by and where condition, right?

Comment: Yes. Indexes are likely to make a massive difference to the time the queries take to execute.